# Docker compose Nginx access static file 404 error

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` for deploying Nodejs(KeystoneJS) app. 
I want to access a static png by the url like: **http://localhost:3000/uploads/apks/5e1ac55962c6a800230d67fb-test.png**
Right now I got 404 error.

There are 3 containers, `Nginx, app, mongo`.

**Folder structre**

- apks
- myapp

  - Dockfile
  - docker-compose.yml

Here is my structure:

[image]

- The images are under `apks`
- Set set static alias in Nginx config file to docker app container folder: `/home/node/static/apks/`

**default.conf**

```
upstream my_app {
  server 192.168.1.119:3000;
}

server {
        listen *:80;
        listen [::]:80;       

        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server-cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server-key.pem;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass http://my_app;
        }

    location /uploads/apks/ {
         alias /home/node/static/apks/;
         types {
          image/png png;
          image/jpeg jpg;
        }
    }   

}
```

- When request get in, then Nginx point to `/home/node/static/apks/`, and because this volume was mounted to the real path in the OS `./apks`, so should response the images there.

I am not sure what's the problem? or if any permission issues.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ../apks:/home/node/static/apks
        - /xxx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
        - /xxx/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - app
  app:
    container_name: my-app
    image: my-app
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
        - ../apks:/home/node/static/apks

    ports:
       - "3000:3000"
    links:
        - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always

    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

**Dockfile**

```
# https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/node/
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.10.0
# https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases
ARG DUMB_INIT_VERSION=1.2.2

# Build container
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS build
ARG DUMB_INIT_VERSION

WORKDIR /home/node

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base python2 yarn && \
    wget -O dumb-init -q https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v${DUMB_INIT_VERSION}/dumb-init_${DUMB_INIT_VERSION}_amd64 && \
    chmod +x dumb-init
ADD . /home/node
RUN yarn install && yarn build && yarn cache clean

# Runtime container
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node

COPY --from=build /home/node /home/node

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./dumb-init", "yarn", "start"]
```

here is the error log:

```
{"level":30,"time":1578817809651,"pid":35,"hostname":"5bb05c547cb6","req":{"id":3,"method":"GET","url":"/uploads/apks/5e1ac55962c6a800230d67fb-Screenshot%202019-12-21%20at%201.01.18%20AM.png","headers":{"host":"localhost:3000","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","cookie":"keystone.sid=s%3Abg7rFgPthjLPes_UWkW2KLI5_HJUVTPN.5shrIzmAUa7zxiq5r5eMhr4N%2BcGlwicwA5Bbim4iV7s","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Safari/605.1.15","accept-language":"en-sg","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","connection":"keep-alive"},"remoteAddress":"::ffff:172.20.0.1","remotePort":43074},"res":{"statusCode":404,"headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","x-keystone-app-version":"1.0.0","vary":"Origin, Accept-Encoding","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","content-security-policy":"default-src 'none'","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":224}},"responseTime":2,"msg":"request completed","v":1}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Apparently request was proxy passed and not processed by Nginx. You will need to improve nginx location configs.

Comment: @JanGaraj Could you a bit more specific? What does it mean by "not processed by Nginx"? I have no clue at all,  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved by changing the permission of my static file folder 
`sudo chmod -R 755 ~/apks`.